# How to calculate the mean of a stack of arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

my stack is something like this

```
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]],

       [[2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2]]])
```

I want this result:

```
array([[ 1.5,  2. ,  2.5],
       [ 3. ,  3.5,  4. ],
       [ 4.5,  5. ,  5.5]])
```

*I updated my question I think it's more clearer now.*

Comment: A stack of 2D arrays would be a 3D array, not three separate variables.

Comment: The mean of 4, 7, and 3 is 4.666666666666667, not 4. Did you want to truncate it, or round it, or did you want the median or median-of-modes or something else rather than the mean?

Comment: I need a floating number (4.666), it was only an example, sorry for confussing

Comment: Your edit changed from 3 2x2 arrays to a single array of shape 2x3x3. Is that actually what you wanted, or did you want a 3x2x2 array as your example, or something different? At any rate, you seem to want to average across axis 0, just as you previously wanted to average across the "external axis", so your edit shouldn't change anything. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first, you don't have a stack of 2D arrays, you have three separate variables.

Fortunately, most functions in NumPy take an `array_like` argument. And the tuple `(a, b, c)` is "array-like" enough—it'll be converted into the 3D array that you should have had in the first place.

Anyway, the obvious function to take the mean is [`np.mean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html). As the docs say:

> The average is taken over the flattened array by default, otherwise over the specified axis.

So just specify the axis you want—the newly-created axis 0.

```
np.mean((a,b,c), axis=0)
```

---

In your updated question, you now have a single 2x3x3 array, `a`, instead of three 2x2 arrays, `a`, `b`, and `c`, and you want the mean across the first axis (the one with dimension 2). This is the same thing, but slightly easier:

```
np.mean(a, axis=0)
```

---

Or course the mean of 4, 7, and 3 is 4.666666666666667, not 4. In your updated question, that seems to be what you want; in your original question… I'm not sure if you wanted to truncate or round, or if you wanted the median or something else rather than the mean, or anything else, but those are all easy (add `dtype=int64` to the call, call `.round()` on the result, call `median` instead of `mean`, etc.).

Comment: @gustavgans: OK, so does that mean this is all you want (except, of course, with your updated question, it's now just `np.mean(a, axis=0)`)?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> b = np.array([[1,5],[6,7]])
>>> c = np.array([[1,8],[8,3]])
>>> np.mean((a,b,c), axis=0)
array([[ 1.        ,  5.        ],
       [ 5.66666667,  4.66666667]])
```

As per your output it seems you are looking for **median** rather than **mean**.

```
>>> np.median((a,b,c), axis=0)
array([[ 1.,  5.],
       [ 6.,  4.]])
```

Comment: Why are you doing all that extra work? Just call `np.mean`. (Also, I think he _may_ want the mean, but he just wanted integers, rather than floats. But I could be wrong.)